# SQL-запрос. Получить список сотрудников, поработавших абсолютно за всеми игровыми столами

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Помогите пожалуйста, как получить список сотрудников, поработавших абсолютно за всеми игровыми столами без вложенных запросов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы попытались решить? Добавте запрос.

Comment: вложенные здесь не нужны, а вот подзапрос понадобится...

Comment: @pavel Не хочу спамить и развивать тему, но подзапрос и вложенный запрос - это одно и то же.

Comment: А может Номер стола это все же числовое поле?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
SELECT ID_WORKER,  COUNT (DISTINCT ID_TABLE) FROM WORKERS  
GROUP BY ID_WORKER
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID_TABLE) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID_TABLE) FROM 
TABLES)
```

Comment: Не соответствует постановке задачи, так как используется подзапрос.

Answer (score 0):

Запрос 1:

Получаем общее кол-во столов `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tables`

Запрос 2:

Считаем кол-во столов на каждого сотрудника, уникализировав по ID стола, фильтруем тех, у кого столов != общему кол-ву столов.

```
SELECT workers.id, COUNT(DISTINCT tables.id) table_count FROM workers
JOIN tables ON tables.id = workers.table_id 
GROUP BY workers.id
HAVING table_count = значение_из_первого_запроса
```

PS: не проверял и совсем не уверен, что данный способ будет работать быстрее чем подзапросы.

Comment: Просто берем и ставим первый запрос вместо `значение_из_первого_запроса`...

Comment: @Dmitry можно так, но тогда не соответствует задаче не использовать подзапросы.